# How to source a remote file hosted on gitlab in R?

Tags: r, gitlab

I have an internal repository on Gitlab.

In my R script I want to `source` an `.R` file from that internal repository.

Normally I can source a publicly available R script with the following code

`source("public-path-to-file")`

But When I try to do that with a private file I get:

```
Error in source("") : 
  :1:1: unexpected '<'
1: <
    ^
```

Comment: Try `readLines()` (used internally in `source`) to at least get the full error message.

Comment: As for the actual authentication (otherwise you will not get access to the private repository), you can have a look at the [credentials](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/credentials/vignettes/intro.html) package. I havent used it for sourcing a single file, but it works well with git2r and remotes.

Comment: Your error `unexpected '<'` is because gitlab will return a HTML file at the given url starting with `<!DOCTYPE html>`. You really need the credentials package

Comment: Does the credential package also work for gitlab? @danlooo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a hacky way to do it that at least gets things done:

First you need to create a private token with api access. Then you can call gitlab's API directly to GET the file

Code:

```
cmd <- "curl -s --header 'PRIVATE-TOKEN: <your private token for gitlab with api access>' '<full gitlab link of the raw file that you want to source>'" # you directly access the API with your private token

output <- system(cmd, intern=TRUE) # capturing the output of the system call

writeLines(output, "functions.R") # creating a temporary file which contains the output of the API call

source("functions.R") # Sourcing the file the usual way

file.remove("functions.R") # removing the temporary file for housekeeping
```

Explanation:

We call the API directly with a GET request using the system command curl.

Then you call the system command through R, capturing the result.

And then you can create a temporary file with the respective contents and source it as you would normally do. Hope this may help someone